# Setting :remember_me on sessions controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been following the Michael Hartl rails tutorial which has worked great so far, but I have run into an issue I can't seem to work out.

I have updated my form from a **form_for** to a **form_tag** and with this, have had to amend my sessions_controller.

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  layout "sessions"

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

**/sessions/new.html**

```
<%= form_tag({ url: login_path }, { class: "form-horizontal" }) do %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-24">
                <div class="floatl hasFloatLabel">
                  <%= label_tag :email, "Email address", class: "floatl__label" %>
                  <%= email_field_tag :email, params[:email], placeholder: "Email address", class: "form-control floatl__input" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group margin-bottom-sm">
              <div class="col-lg-24">
                <div class="floatl hasFloatLabel">
                  <%= label_tag :password, "Password", class: "floatl__label" %>
                  <%= password_field_tag :password, nil, placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control floatl__input" %>
                  <em><a href="#">Forgot your Password?</a></em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group margin-bottom-sm">
              <div class="col-lg-24">
                <div class="floatl hasFloatLabel">
                  <%= check_box_tag :remember_me, nil, placeholder: "Remember Me", class: "form-control floatl__input" %>
                  <p class="remember-me">Remember me?</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-24">
                <%= submit_tag "Login", class: "btn btn-brand" %>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
```

This seems to break when trying to set a remember_token and if I remove [:session] from the code, it lets me log in, but doesn't set a remember_token.

Have I missed something or is there an easier way to set this token?

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

Comment: can you post what you have the remember and forget methods in the sessions helper?  can you post your sessions helper?

Comment: Just updated the original post

Comment: what is breaking - please paste the error . also, is the controller including the session_helper?

Comment: I've added the above for both @RockwellRice

It simply doesn't set the remember_token anymore. Login still works as expected.

Comment: @Joel_Blum Added the requested info.

Comment: @JamesPardigan  does you application controller include the session helper?

Comment: @RockwellRice It does indeed. I have followed everything from the [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/advanced_login).